# HTML select not inflating correctly from PHP array

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a drop down menu of usernames or a `<select>` as it's known in `HTML`. However I am only getting the last value back from my array and I can't figure out why.

**PHP**

```
function getUserName($db) {

    try {
        $sql = 'SELECT members.name FROM members';
        $query_an = $db->query($sql);               
        $count = $query_an->rowCount();

        if ($count > 0) {
            while ($row = $query_an->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $names = array();   
                $names[] = $row['name'];                                
            }
            return $names;          
        }       
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select>                        
  <?php $names = getUserName($db); foreach($names as $key => $value) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

I'm fairly sure the `HTML` section of my code is solid. I think the error lies in how I'm adding values to my $names array but after staring at it for a half an hour I can't see it. Thanks for any help/fresh eyes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare your array outside the loop

```
if ($count > 0) {
    $names = array(); 
    while ($row = $query_an->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $names[] = $row['name'];                                
    }
    return $names;          
}
```

Answer (score 2):

this is emptying your array every time : `$names = array();`

use this :

```
while ($row = $query_an->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $names[] = $row['name'];                                
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a new `$names` array every row then returning the last one. You need to declare the array outside the while loop. The following should work:

```
function getUserName($db) {

try {
    $sql = 'SELECT members.name FROM members';
    $query_an = $db->query($sql);               
    $count = $query_an->rowCount();

    if ($count > 0) {
        $names = array();
        while ($row = $query_an->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $names[] = $row['name'];                                
        }
        return $names;          
    }       
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die($e->getMessage());
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you're re-initializing the array on every loop:

See:

```
while ($row = $query_an->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                $names = array();   
                $names[] = $row['name'];                                
            }
            return $names;
```

Should be:

```
$names = array(); 
 while ($row = $query_an->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {                      
                $names[] = $row['name'];                                
            }
            return $names;
```